# cannot display sql data inside gridview

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net

I am trying the following in order to display the sql table data inside a gridview

```
try
    {
        SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection();
        xconn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=servername;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=master";
        xconn.Open();

        string s = "select * from tablename";
        SqlCommand ycmd = new SqlCommand(s,xconn);
        SqlDataReader dr = ycmd.ExecuteReader();

        gridview.DataSource = dr;
        gridview.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        lblresult.Text = "Cannot connect to SQL";
    }
```

I keep getting an exception. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exception you are receiving?

Comment: I am thinking you cannot bind a datareader to a grid.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception, and what is the exception?

Comment: @Brettski - you can bind to a DataReader().  There's an example (similar to this code) on this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860  Search for ExecuteReader() - it's about halfway down.

Comment: True enough, forgot about that.

Comment: I see [Initial Catalog=master] in your connection string. Is your table in the system [master] database? Just confirming. When you trace, does the exception get thrown at the line .Open() or further below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the Catch section with

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblresult.Text = ex.Message &"\n" & ex.StackTrace;
}
```

Now you will get a valid exception description. use that to fix it yourself... :)

If not, post the detailed exception information from the `lblresult.Text` in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You must fill the request result in a varible which you can use as itemsource.

```
GridView.ItemsSource = ContainerClass.AllItems;
```

The ContainerClass is a help class and contains a IEnumerable AllItems variable. The gridview can show the values on this way!!